# Having trouble using jQuery change() with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add/remove a class and attribute to a few labels and input boxes depending on whether or not a checkbox is checked or not.

By default my check box is set up to be not checked. Here is my existing code...

```
$("#built").change(function()
{
    $("label.readonly").removeClass("readonly");
    $("input.readonly").removeAttr("readonly");
}).change();
```

For some reason the event isn't firing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Update:

Here is my html code

```
<label for="address1" class="readonly">Address Line 1</label>

<input type="text" name="address1" class="readonly" readonly="readonly" value="" />
```

Also, upon the check box being unchecked I would like the labels and inputs to revert back to its original state of having the readonly class and attribute respectively.

Comment: We need some HTML information to see how it's built.

Comment: I doubt that the onChange event is an appropiate event for checkboxes.

Comment: why is your code not checking the state of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason your code won't work, maybe just indentation or something like this.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s94BV/1/) with your function and it's working.

I just removed the line break like this:

```
$("#build").change(function() {
    $("label.readonly").removeClass("readonly");
    $("input.readonly").removeAttr("readonly");
});
```

Maybe there are other javascript problems somewhere else in the page?

Comment: hmm...this looks like it but its not removing the readonly attribute from the input field.

Comment: I just forgot the "readonly" class on the input, that's why... Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s94BV/3/

Comment: This does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.change()` after the function and add a `;`.

eg:

```
$("#built").change(function(){
    $("label.readonly").removeClass("readonly");
    $("input.readonly").removeAttr("readonly");
});
```